# Getting mongoengine and django rest framework to play nice

Tags: django, mongoengine, django-rest-framework

I am wondering how I can get mongoengine and djangoRESTframework to work with each other. Currently, my model is

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class Blog(Document):
    post_id = IntField(unique=True)
    title = StringField(max_length=144, required=True)
    date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    body = StringField(required=True)
```

and I have the serializer defined as

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import *

class BlogList(APIView):
    """
    Lists all blog posts, or creates a new post
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        posts = Blog.objects.to_json()
        return Response(posts)
```

But I am receiving the error

```
TypeError at /blog/

__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

which gives the following traceback

```
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django REST Framework is intended to work well with Django's models. As MongoEngine is not a replacement for Django's Models, you will need to define a few more functions for it to play nice with Django Rest framework.

If you need a framework build for MongoEngine, you might want to take a look at [django-tastypie-mongoengine](http://django-tastypie-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead.

If you prefer to use Django REST Framework it's perfectly feasible though. Your `BlogList` class is actually a View, not a Serializer. First, define a serializer class:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Blog

class BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    post_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=144)
    date_created = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    body = serializers.CharField()

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance is not None:
            for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
                setattr(instance, k, v)
            return instance
        return Blog(**attrs)
```

Since the MongoEngine Document is not a Django Model instance, you need to create the objects yourself instead of inheriting from `serializers.ModelSerializer`. That is why the `restore_object` method is here. From the [documentation](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html): Given a dictionary of deserialized field values, [it will] either update an existing model instance, or create a new model instance.

Then you can define your view, e.g.

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Blog

class BlogList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects
```

Again, Django REST Framework expects a few things of a standard Django models which are not verified by MongoEngine Documents, hence the need to redefine the `get_queryset` method.

Then in your urls.py, add:

```
url(r'^blog/', BlogList.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
```

Comment: It turned out my problem was that I did not have the .as_view() in my urls.py file. What is weird is that I have not always needed it for views using restlib2.

Comment: It seems restlib2 `Resource` classes are plain old callable views, i.e. `Resource()` just calls `Resource.dispatch()` while Django REST Frameworks uses Django's Class Based Views (http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views.html and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) which do require the use of `as_view()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Monkful](https://github.com/gitaarik/monkful), it's like Django Rest Framework, but it works with MongoEngine.

Comment: This tool is built for Flask, the question was oriented to Django.

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to mid-2016. Now we have [Django-REST-Framework-Mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine). It's still quite far from being a complete turnkey solution, but at least the partial functionality that it currently provides is well-covered with unit-tests. So, come on, let's improve it.

Comment: Regardless of its features, is it stable for production ?

Comment: @Ahmed no, it is not. But we're getting closer. We run several internal services on it in our company and it served us well.