# Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions when rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly is enabled

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am trying to make MongoEngine work with Django REST framework. By following this link [Getting mongoengine and django rest framework to play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221598/getting-mongoengine-and-django-rest-framework-to-play-nice/17223228#17223228), I manage to get everything working, but have to disable "PERMISSION CLASSES" in REST framework, like below

`'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    #'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
]`

Otherwise, I get this error "Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.model` or `.queryset` property.". The reason seems to be that the returned value from "Collection.objects" or "Collection.objects.all()" can not pass "has_permission" function in permission.py in REST framework.

Could anyone help to look at this?

Comment: Could you post your view code here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have \`.queryset\` property or overrides the \`.get\_queryset()\` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335736/cannot-apply-djangomodelpermissions-on-a-view-that-does-not-have-queryset-pro)

Answer (score 7):

Or you can just add:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
```

and in the view classes add

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

Answer (score 5):

In your views.py import the following models:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
```

Before declaring the function (the view function) add:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
```

or

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
```

Comment: this doesn't work with classbased view. Please update the answer to be more specific.

Comment: I wouldnt say it would be the best answer. Since the` DjangoModelPermissions` is basically to manage permissions based on roles/groups.

Answer (score 1):

As per Django REST docs:

> This permission class ties into Django's standard django.contrib.auth
> model permissions. **This permission must only be applied to views
> that have a .queryset property or get_queryset() method.**

This means that on your view, you must have the queryset properly set, e.g:

```
queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
```

Best approach will be to authenticate at a view-base level. So your view must look like this:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly

class SampleAPIView(APIView):
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly,]
```

And just in case you are using JWT authentication, you just need to add this to `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```